# Regex to detect filling character length with periods

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build some regex that would detect when someone is trying to "fill out" their username with dots.

There are a few other requirements:

- username must contain only letters, numbers and dots
- username must start and end with a letter or number
- but not more than one consecutive dot
- minimum of 6 characters (letters and numbers)

e.g.:

- a.b.c.d.e.6 is allowed (not caught) because it has 6 characters
- a.b.c.d.5 is not (is caught) because it does not have the prerequisite 6 characters

The way that I'm building the regex is if there's a match, it will reject the username allowed.

What I have thus far is:

```
/[^a-z0-9.]|^\.|\.$|\.{2,}|\S{31,}|^\S{0,5}$/i
```

This catches:

- any characters that aren't letters, numbers, dots
- can't start with a dot
- can't end with a dot
- can't have 2 or more consecutive dots
- can't have 31 or more characters
- can't have 5 or less characters

I've tried dozens of different ways to get that last check in place, but they've all either broken the entire check, included the allowable (a.b.c.d.e.6) or just not worked.

the one that I've come closest with is:

```
(\.{1}[a-z0-9]{1,}){1,3}\S{1,}$
```

The problem with this is that it's also catching 123.456 (which should be allowed / not caught)

other examples of character strings that it should catch:

- asdf.g
- a.sdfg
- a.sdf.g
- as.df.g

I'm trying to do this using only regex, without having to pre-format it using JS.

Comment: Would the `.length` property suffice? It should make your expression less complex.

Comment: Anything wrong with trying to match on `\.\.`?

Comment: What about using a *matching* regex and checking for no match: http://jsfiddle.net/ew88c8wt/2/ ? The regex at regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/qS7mY5/1

Comment: I am not sure your reverse requirements are appropriate, have a look at the result: https://regex101.com/r/qS7mY5/2

Comment: @npinti, Thanks, but i'm trying to do this as much with regex as possible.

Comment: @Bohemian, I've considered that, but I think it would end up being more work - I'll look into it again soon

Comment: @stribizhev NIce, I'll be looking in more detail in a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much experimentation I've actually found the answer. It turns out that finding the non-permitted strings was actually easier (for me anyway):

```
/^(\w\.?){4}\w$/
```

same expression expanded:

```
/^\w\.?\w\.?\w\.?\w\.?\w$/
```

This will catch anything that is populated with only 5 or fewer characters and interspersed with dots.

The full regex that I'm using also catches:

- Strings of 31 or more characters (alphanumeric and periods).
- Any characters that are not alphanumeric and periods.
- Any string starting with a period
- Any string ending with a period
- Any string that has 2 or more consecutive periods
- And a new-comer to the list: Any string that has 8 or more numeric digits without any alpha.

  ```
  /^(\w\.?){4}\w$|^\w{0,5}$|\w{31,}|[^a-z0-9.]|^\.|\.$|\.{2,}|\d{8,}/i
  ```

I've tested this with all the possible combinations that I can think of on regex101 here: https://regex101.com/r/xI7wZ3/1
And it works! (yay)